# Fill cells with a repetitive Date pattern in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How would I create a repetitive pattern of "dates" (e.g. 1-Jan-15, 1-Jan-15, 2-Jan-15, 2-Jan-15 .....)

Saw this command in one of the posts =ROUND(ROW()/3,0) which I modified to =ROUND(ROW()/2,42005)  where 42005 is the Excel value for 1 Jan 2015. Apparently that won't work.

Comment: This is probably a StackOverflow question. Please ask it there next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **A1** enter:

```
=ROUNDUP(COLUMN()/2,0)+DATE(2014,12,31)
```

and copy across:

[image]

This adds the pattern:

1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6.............

to a base date.

Comment: Didn't see your solution.  That works too.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Simply created a formula ....
Put My first date in cell A1.
Enter these formulas in the following cells:
A2 - =A1
A3 - =A2 + 1
A4 - =A3
then copied cells A2 - A4

Comment: Your solution is equally good.